# How to refactor the code for tryparse in c#

Tags: c#, refactoring, tryparse

How can I refactor this code segment by removing the bool variable?

```
    bool value = int.TryParse(configHelper.GetConfigValue("timeout"), out time );
    time = value ? time : 70000;
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry It was a mistake when copying the code.Now how can I refactor?

Comment: bool value indicates if parsing is successful or not. If it is successful, you can get the parsed result from time variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time = int.TryParse(configHelper.GetConfigValue("timeout"), out var mgdtimeout) ? mgdtimeout : 70000;
```